# Django and PostgreSQL - value too long for type character varying(512)

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-database

I am migrating from a test SQLite database to a PostgreSQL database.

I have a sample object that is inserted in the database, that worked on SQLite but is giving me an error in PostgreSQL.

Code snippet is:

```
car = CarItem.objects.create(
    user = motor_trend,
    name = 'Camaro 2010',
    category = cars,
    condition = 'Used',
    price = '28,547.00',
    production_year = '2010',
    color_interior = 'Black',
    color_exterior = 'Inferno Orange Metallic',
    reference = 'PRC17288',
    location_of_creation = 'Undisclosed',
    location_current = 'Columbus, OH, USA',
    description = 'GORGEOUS ORANGE SS!!',
)
car.save()
```

I am getting a:

```
DatabaseError at /create/
value too long for type character varying(512)

Traceback
(...)
    description = 'GORGEOUS ORANGE SS!!',
(...)
```

The description field of my model has a 512 max char length:

```
description = models.CharField(max_length=512,default='')
```

But there is no way that string is over 512 bytes.

I have read previous posts about this error, one referring to the encoding. Does not appear to be the case.

I am hosted on Webfaction. I created a database, with utf-8 encoding, and proceeded to use syncdb. Syncdb worked perfectly but now this object insertion fails.

Can somebody give some input? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/databases/):

> Character fields
>
> Any fields that are stored with VARCHAR column types have their
>   max_length **restricted to 255 characters** if you are using **unique=True**
>   for the field.

Emphasis mine. Do you have `unique=True` for the field?
This is a Django restriction, PostgreSQL wouldn't mind. You might want to switch to data type [`text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html). [`TextField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#textfield) in Django parlance.

---

Old ideas:

**`user`** is a [reserved word in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and any SQL standard. Don't use it as column name.

You *could* use it, if you enclosed it in double quotes, but stay away from that folly. Just don't use reserved words for identifiers. Ever.

Also ...

```
user = motor_trend,
name = 'Camaro 2010',
category = cars,
```

Any particular reason why `motor_trend` and `cars` are not quoted like the other values? Foreign keys, like @Ignacio commented?

Comment: Because they're foreign keys. And Django's ORM probably quotes the field names properly.

Comment: Yes, those are Django variables defined previously, some strings, other objects.

However, is this related to the description problem? Is the fact I have a user field causing the description problem?

Comment: @VascoPatricio: No obvious connection to the problem, no. As there was nothing obvious I was hunting for anything suspicious. I dug into the manual and think I found something now. Amended my answer, have a look.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It does make more sense to use a TextField rather than a CharField for long text fields. I will try this and report back.